# A developer made himself owner of a lot of files and folders on the server. He's gone. Should I change ownership to root?

Tags: server, permissions

I have a Ubuntu server that a couple of freelance developers work on, leaving me as administrator for the time being. There are folders that I need to change permissions to in order to access the contents each time. (sudo chmod -R 777) And then back to 755 when I'm done. Do I gain anything if I change ownership to root? Will the permissions still be the same? I suppose my question should be Can someone recommend a good introductory tutorial on ownership and permissions.

Comment: Before doing anything hasty, I would strongly suggest you that you start from the [community Ubuntu guide on file permission](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

In general, I would suggest you to create a `group` of `user`s, assign the ownership of this file to a user of that specific group instead of `root` and assign your user to that group.
This is safer than assigning ownership to root and **a lot** safer than just `chmod 777` everything.

Comment: In your particular case, though, it would be necessary to know what these files are (configs, data, binaries) and where they are (personal folders, shared folders, system folder, ecc) before suggesting a proper solution.